# Angular ng-include is not working with the razor page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razorengine

I have used `ng-include` as shown below.But it is not working.Could you tell me why ? Thanks in advance.

***createOrEditPropertyModal.cshtml***

```
<div ng-include="'propertymanagement/tabs/createPropertyForm.html'"></div>
```

I have tried this way also.But same `404` error.

```
 <div ng-include="'tabs/createPropertyForm.html'"></div>
```

***createPropertyForm.cshtml***

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="createPropertyForm.html">
    <form name="createPropertyForm" role="form">

       //removed for clarity

    </form>
</script>
```

***Soloution Tree***

[image]

**Note :** When I put it on the same page then it works.But how can I do that in above way ? B'cos I would like to put that code on separate `.cshtml` file.

```
 <div ng-include="'createPropertyForm.html'"></div> //on same page where this works well
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Method 1 : OP's Answer**

You can do this.Here is the way.You have to give the full path as shown below.

```
<div ng-include="'~/App/tenant/views/propertymanagement/tabs/createPropertyForm.cshtml'"></div>
```

If you have any performance issues then check it out here : [ng-Include is very slow with the external template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794053/ng-include-is-very-slow-with-the-external-template)

**Method 2 :**

you cant include .cshtml page by using ng-include

for it you have to go with proper routing of mvc ,Like

```
   <div ng-include="'controller/Template/createPropertyForm'"></div>
```

here createPropertyForm will be like a id part of a action method

```
    public ActionResult Template(string id)
     {
    switch (id.ToLower())
    {
        case "createPropertyForm":
            return PartialView("~/Views/propertymanagement/tabs/createPropertyForm.cshtml");

        default:
            throw new Exception("template not known");
    }
}
```

otherwise just create a html page and access it as

```
   <div ng-include="'createPropertyForm.html'"></div>
```

Comment: Could you tell me why this behaves differently on *.cshtml pages and *.html pages ? Thanks.

Comment: @Sampath  by [Anguler Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) , ng-include Fetches, compiles and includes an external HTML fragment . And cshtml is html + server code. so first by mvc cycle it will get pure html then can include it. as per my understanding.

Comment: @Sampath `return View()` or `return PartialView()` tells MVC to generate proper  HTML and send it back, which can be used by `ng-include` to add it on the page. Hope it will help you. - thanks

Comment: Thanks for the support :)