# ng-Include is very slow with the external template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have used `ng-include` as shown below.But it is very slow.In other words it shows tab's heading without the content of it.Later it loads the content.Which is really BAD.But if I use all the content on the same page then there is no delay.So how can I speed this ? Do you know any trick or method to do that ? Thanks.

***Parent page :***

```
<uib-tab heading="@L("PropertyInformation")">
<div ng-include="'~/App/tenant/views/propertymanagement/createPropertyForm.cshtml'"></div>
</uib-tab>
```

***Template : createPropertyForm.cshtml***

```
     <form name="createPropertyForm" role="form" novalidate class="form-validation">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label no-hint">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="StreetNumber" ng-model="vm.property.address.streetNumber" ng-class="{'edited':vm.property.address.streetNumber}" required maxlength="@Address.MaxLength">
                            <label>@L("StreetNumber")</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label no-hint">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="StreetName" ng-model="vm.property.address.streetName" ng-class="{'edited':vm.property.address.streetName}" required maxlength="@Address.MaxLength">
                            <label>@L("StreetName")</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">@L("City")</label>
                            <select ng-model="vm.property.address.cityId" class="form-control" ng-options="a.id as a.name + ' | '+ a.zipCode for a in vm.cities" required>
                                <option value="" disabled="">-- Select a City --</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

// having lot more elements
```

When I use above as shown below,then no delays.But I would like to separate those html content to separate template.That is why I have tried above.

***All in the same page :***

```
    <uib-tab heading="@L("PropertyInformation")">
       <div ng-include="'createPropertyForm.html'"></div>
    </uib-tab> 

 <script type="text/ng-template" id="createPropertyForm.html">
        <form name="createPropertyForm" role="form" novalidate class="form-validation">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label no-hint">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="StreetNumber" ng-model="vm.property.address.streetNumber" ng-class="{'edited':vm.property.address.streetNumber}" required maxlength="@Address.MaxLength">
                        <label>@L("StreetNumber")</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label no-hint">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="StreetName" ng-model="vm.property.address.streetName" ng-class="{'edited':vm.property.address.streetName}" required maxlength="@Address.MaxLength">
                        <label>@L("StreetName")</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">@L("City")</label>
                        <select ng-model="vm.property.address.cityId" class="form-control" ng-options="a.id as a.name + ' | '+ a.zipCode for a in vm.cities" required>
                            <option value="" disabled="">-- Select a City --</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
</script>
```

Comment: you should cache your html templates

Comment: @entre Could you tell me how to do that ? May be as an answer below.Thanks.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle that shows the slowdown when you're loading from a separate template?

Comment: @LloydBanks I don't think it is possible b'cos you can see that I'm loading server content like this `maxlength="@Address.MaxLength"`.And this is not a `html` page.This is a `cshtml` page (razor).Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution.You can use **[$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache)** service.

**app.js**

```
appModule.run(["$templateCache", "$http", function ($templateCache, $http) {
    $http.get('~/App/tenant/views/propertymanagement/tabs/createPropertyForm.cshtml', { cache: $templateCache });

}]);
```

**cshtml page**

```
  <div ng-include="'~/App/tenant/views/propertymanagement/tabs/createPropertyForm.cshtml'"></div>
```

Comment: The above solution worked really well for me. I just hope it does not causes caching issues.

Comment: No issues at all. I have used this with one of my production app and working really well :) @rach8garg

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the template cache generator like [grunt-html2js](https://github.com/karlgoldstein/grunt-html2js)

But according angularjs documentation you can cache a template nesting the content as:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="templateId.html">
    <p>This is the content of the template</p>
</script>
```

And then normally include the template:

```
<div ng-include=" 'templateId.html' "></div>
```

Comment: I have done this with the same page as I mentioned it on the above post.Then no delays.But How can I do this with the external template ?  Thanks.

Comment: In other words the path like this `~/App/tenant/views/propertymanagement/createPropertyForm.cshtml` ?