# Page render speed in AngularJS using ng-include

Tags: angularjs

I've got an issue where I populate a page in pieces.  There are an arbitrary number of categories with an arbitrary number of items.  The code is generally something like the below (warning, transposed).

```
$scope.getItems = function(key) {
  $http.get('get-items?key=' + key)
  .then(function(res) {
    for (let item of res.data) {
       $scope.categories[item.category].items.push(item);
    } 
  });
}

let populateCategories = function() {
  for (let key in $scope.categories) {
    $scope.getItems(key);
  }
}

$scope.getCategories = function(next) {
  $http.get('get-categories')
  .then(function(res) {
    $scope.categories = res.data;
    next();
  });

  $scope.getCategories(populateCategories);
}
```

The idea is to first get what categories will be on the page, and render them, empty (but w/ a busy icon).  After that, hit and endpoint one time per category and populate w/ the results.  The busy icon is shown via ng-show & a boolean pointing to the size of the items.  1 or more items = no busy icon, an the items should show.

The loading of the categories more or less works.  Populating them though, is not so free flowing.  Watching the console output, it takes ages for the browser to render.  The busy icon goes away somewhat quickly, but I don't see the items until a bunch of them are ready.

Worth noting, (I think) I saw this problem appear when I moved the html that displays each item from a single file, an template and used ng-include, as I'm using it on two different places.  Surely that would not be a cause would it?

EDIT: Adding the html - simplified

item-template.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2 col">
    <img src="{{item.img}}">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-10 col">
    <div>{{item.details}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

list.html

```
<body>
  <div class ="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in categories">
        <div>{{key}}</div>
        <div ng-show="value.busy"">
          <img ng-src="{{busy_image}}">
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="item in value.items track by $index">
          <!-- This in fact seems to be the culprit -->
          <div ng-include="item-template.html">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

So, playing around, if I simply paste the contents of template.html into list.html, the response is much, much better.  Looking at this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794053/ng-include-is-very-slow-with-the-external-template), the solution seems to be to use a cache service. I'm happy to use something like that but I'm still curious as to why. The template I'm using isn't small (166 lines) but I can't imagine it being that heavy either on a modern computer.

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Comment: Added - w/ a finding

Answer (score 1):

Several things from the top of head:

- amount of items to be shown in the HTML. Large lists with x properties = alot of Angular watchers.
- if there are alot of items, maybe check for an alternative to ng-repeat
- instead of ng-include item-template.html, create a Component
- ng-repeat with track by
- use bind once
- in this case you can replace ng-show with ng-if

Comment: I should have mentioned the volume.  In my tests i'm doing like < 10 categories and initially I only allow 5 items to be loaded per.  I realize lazy loading might be a better long term goal, but this doesn't seem like a painful load to me.